# Long-term support for OCX / ActiveX

Tags: com-interop, ocx

In order to create a new application, I intend to purchase a certain component which is only available as an OCX, not as a .Net component.  My question is: has there been any rumblings about discontinued support for COM interop in Visual Studio in the foreseeable future?

Thanks!

Comment: COM is everywhere in Windows (WinRT, etc.), so it won't go away any time soon. However a vendor that only has OCX is quite limiting itself and is often the sign of poor reaction to the market IMHO. Most vendors propose at least .NET wrappers over their native components (and some also provide 100% managed equivalents)

Comment: Well, in this case, the ActiveX component is fully supported through interop.  It just bugs me to put good money on something which isn't based on a .NET foundation given that this is for a long lifespan application.  I wouldn't want to learn in 10 years from now that Windows won't support the application because of an ActiveX if no .NET replacement is available.  That's happened to me a lot in the past....